# Why doesn't conservation of energy apply to a block sliding from a hemispherical bowl?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, collision

I made this question

> Two identical masses are released from rest in a smooth hemispherical bowl of a radius *R* from the positions sown in the figure below. Ignore friction between the masses and the surface of the bowl. If the masses stick together when they collide, how high above the bottom of the bowl will they go after colliding?
>
> [image]

I tried solving it using the law of conversation of energy. So:

$$ m g R = 2 mgh $$
$$ h = R/2 $$

However, this is **wrong**. The answer to the question also uses the law of conversation in momentum. So first calculate the the speed of the sliding block at the bottom:

$$ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 = mgR $$
$$ v= \sqrt{2gR} $$

Afterwards, the speed of the two blocks is calculated at the bottom.

$$ mv_1 = 2mv_2 $$
$$ v_2 = v_1/2 $$
$$ v_2 = \sqrt{gR/2} $$

Then using conversation of energy again for the two blocks sliding upwards

$$ \frac{1}{2}(2m)v_2^2 =(2m)gh $$
$$ h = v_2^2/2g = R/4 $$

$ R/4 $ is clearly not $ R/2 $. Something seems wrong with my logic. Could someone point out why I can't simply use óne equation using the conversation of energy.

Additional question: if $ h= R/4 $, that would mean that the total energy of the two blocks together at $ h= R/4 $ is smaller than the total energy of one block before it slides down from $ h = R $ by a factor of 2. Where did this energy go?

Comment: Energy was not conserved during one part of this process, but it's not got anything to do with the bowl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two bodies stick together after the collision, it generally means that the collision is not elastic and the "kinetic" energy is not conserved during the collision.

You can try to work out a special situation where there are two bodies of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ with the initial velocities $u_1$ and $u_2$ colliding with each other and stick together afterward. By writing down the kinetic energy before the collision and after the collision, you will be able to see that there is an energy lost during this process.

Edit: Include the point that @gan raised.

Comment: To be specific, it's kinetic energy that is not conserved, as some of it gets dissipated as vibrational energy, heat etc. Total energy is conserved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will include your point to my comment!

Comment: This kind of exercise let me with a bitter taste as it is not specified how much kinetic energy is lost and this is dependent upon material. There is not net balance. The exercise remain the same independent of the two masses constitution. ...